# Access 2013 Web App Filter Combo box value based on other field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-web-app

I am modifying an Access 2013 web app.
I have a combobox (lookup field with user entered list) in List form view.

Now I need to filter values in this combobox based on other field. The other field is in the same table as text field.

I need to filter values in combobox if that other field is null or not null.

I have tried to create a table for combobox, I have also tried to create a query with parameter but from list view when I select query for my combobox I couldnt pass parameter.

When I select table it brings whole table which is same as entering values.

Let me know if you know any work around.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a similar similar scenario I was able to make query that filtered the table and then I added a new combobox the row source should be the name of query and bound Field should be the name of the column